# Send option/alt key press to OS X connected from Windows via VNC?

Tags: macos, vnc, keyboard-layout

I recently started using a mac running Leopard Server remotely at work, using the RealVNC client to connect from my Windows XP workstation via the Leopard VNC server.

As I need to do a fair amount of editing, I would like to have the keys mapped to the same positions as the macs I have been using for a long time. The Ctrl key works as Ctrl, and the Alt key works as Cmd, which is good, but I have had no success getting the Windows logo key to work as Option/Alt. It's seriously affecting my productivity in XCode and Terminal.

Has anybody with the same setup solved this question, either by configuring Windows and/or the VNC client, or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem existed as of synergy 1.3.4; was resolved after upgrading client (running on the Mac-side) to 1.3.6p2.

Answer (score 1):

I use Vine VNC server on Mac OS X Leopard, and RealVNC as the client.

My Ctrl key works as Ctrl, Alt key works as Cmd and the Windows Logo key works as Option/Alt. I guess thats what you want, so perhaps try running Vine VNC server on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [x11vnc](http://x11vnc.sf.net) you can remap keys the way you want using the `-remap` option. Besides, `x11vnc` is way better than vine (in speed) and built-in vnc (in stability, e.g., clipboard sharing), and can be started and stopped remotely (e.g., you can ssh into the box and kill/start `x11vnc` from command-line). I just tried to remap Left Shift key to act as Enter key just for the heck of it and it worked, try this:

```
x11vnc -rfbauth ~/.vnc/passwd -remap Shift_L-Return
```

Note that you need to explicitly specify the authentication method for `x11vnc`, or it will start with NO authentication. In this case, I created the password using `x11vnc -storepasswd ~/.vnc/passwd` in advance, but you can also use the passwd file created by other vnc servers. Also note that, though the name indicates dependency on `x11`, it does NOT require X11 to be running. The names of the keys can be looked up from the `keysymdef.h` (`/usr/include/X11`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use RealVNC client to have "Option" key enabled: both TightVNC and UltraVNC viewers do not send the "Option" key (which should be mapped to "windows" key).

See the whole response here: [Option-key with VNC Viewer to remote control a Mac from a Windows 7 PC](https://superuser.com/questions/193604/option-key-with-vnc-viewer-to-remote-control-a-mac-from-a-windows-7-pc/644340#644340)